# Got error when creating procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to get the info from table `s` via inputting specific student name.

Code goes like this:

```
delimiter //
    `CREATE PROCEDURE get_info_hujiamin (IN sn_input VARCHAR)  
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM s
    WHERE s.sn=sn_input;
END`
 //
```

Comment: If you get any error message please share it to us.

Comment: i am using navicat for mac and the error goes like this Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  
BEGIN
 SELECT *
 FROM s
 WHERE s.sn=sn_input;
END' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do query like below: here you haven't added length of VARCHAR

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN countryName VARCHAR(255))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM offices
 WHERE country = countryName;
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can also refer [My SQL Procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot:) and i will check more carefully next time.